# Virtually click the "Back to [app]" button in iOS9 Safari

Tags: mobile-safari, ios9

Our team is building an iOS app which links out to Safari to process a charitable donation flow. In iOS 8, we can return the user back to the app by setting document.location to the app's custom URL scheme (e.g. myappscheme://donation/success), and everything flows fine for the user.

In iOS 9, Apple appear to have tightened their security model to display a popup dialog when exercising custom URL schemes in Safari - this allows the user to click "Cancel" and not link [back] out to the app.

My question is, given that iOS 9 now has a "< Back to [app]" button in the header of Safari - is there a way to 'tap' that link via JavaScript, rather than having to resort to a custom scheme, or Apple's new Universal Links mechanism?

Virtually clicking "Back to [app]" is desirable as it makes Safari slide back away to the right (the inverse of the way Safari now slides in from the right), rather than "re-opening" our app, like it does after clicking "OK" on the popup dialog. It also would stop iOS from putting a "Back to Safari" link in the top-left of our app which, is what happens when our app is opened via a Universal Link or Custom Schema.

Comment: You got any idea on this to fix?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, or at least, Apple doesn't want you to. They've precisely implemented this mechanism to avoid this kind of automatic-fly-back-to-my-app scheme. If there were any documented way to do it using the SDK, that would result in a security issue.

However, in iOS 9, there is a new way to do this, and it involves hosting the web content in a Safari View Controller (`SFSafariViewController`), directly inside your app. This way you get all the benefits from Safari (user experience, shared cookies, etc.) *and* the user remains in your app (she can simply close the Safari view by tapping the 'Done' button on the top right corner of the screen).